# Apache webserver drops large text POST variable

Tags: php, apache, http-post, webmin

I am trying to POST a large input type text but on the destination script it shows the POST variable does not exist. I have changed my php.ini settings to the below but still to no avail.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; http://php.net/max-execution-time
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
max_execution_time = 99999

; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data. Its a good
; idea to limit this time on productions servers in order to eliminate unexpectedly
; long running scripts.
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to -1 for the CLI SAPI
; Default Value: -1 (Unlimited)
; Development Value: 60 (60 seconds)
; Production Value: 60 (60 seconds)
; http://php.net/max-input-time
max_input_time = 4800

; Maximum input variable nesting level
; http://php.net/max-input-nesting-level
;max_input_nesting_level = 256

; How many GET/POST/COOKIE input variables may be accepted
; max_input_vars = 10000

; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 2048M
```

The following error on the Apache warning log:
ALERT - configured request variable value length limit exceeded - dropped variable

If I var_dump:
var_dump($file = file_get_contents('php://input'));

I can see the needed post variable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your .htaccess

```
php_value post_max_size 128M
```

This increases the maximum post size to 128MB.

Also, in your php.ini, the 'max_input_vars' is commented out. Enable it and try to increase the value.